# My UV map isn't wiring Properly with my normal direction

Tags: texturing, uv, normals

I'm a bit of an amateur in Blender, but I'm making a mockup LEGO box for a school project, and I can't seem to figure out why my image texture is showing up on the inside panels on my box. Only two panels seem to be at fault. The box has a solidify modifier, but doesn't have any real depth, which is why I set it up this way.

My normals are all facing outwards, and my UV map seems to be set up correctly.

Here is a link to some screens from within blender.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLXxM.jpg

This may not be the correct method of doing this, if that is the case I'll figure out a different method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "UV Map Node" and connect it to the "Vector" of your image texture. While in the "Node Editor" Press "Shift + A" and find the "UV Map Node" under the "Input category.

[image]

Also, make sure that you have selected your image in the UV Editor.

Try this simple node set up.[image]

Comment: I added that node in, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Try this simple node set up:

[UV Map] to “Vector” of [Image Texture] > [Image texture] “Color” to [Diffuse BSDF] “Color” >
[Diffuse BSDF] “BSDF” to [Mix Shader] “Shader” [Glossy BSDF] "BSDF" to [Mix Shader] “Shader” > [Mix Shader] “Shader” to [Material Output] “Surface".

(I will upload an image as soon as I can)

Comment: Like this? The image is now back on both sides of the box. http://imgur.com/a/6UMvj

Comment: Yes. Although, unless something has changed you can only put a texture on one side of a mesh (You see it in the 3D viewport but it wont Render on both sides).